# How to install "Wordpress for ios" on Apple's SDK's iPhone/iPad simulator?

Tags: iphone

How to install [Wordpress for ios](http://ios.wordpress.org/) on Apple's SDK's iPhone/iPad simulator? and what are other ways to make Wordpress Admin compatible with iphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be [answered on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187611/how-to-install-iphone-application-in-iphone-simulator). The accepted answer refers to [a thread on the MacRumors forum](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=547557).

Comment: I don't want to test my own app. I just want to install wordpress for ios.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: If you want to run it in the simulator, I think you will need to download the sources and compile them with Xcode. I don't think you can install an app from the App Store in the simulator. You will probably get better answers on [the Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) or the main Stack Overflow site.